# Pass parameter to virtual entity data provider plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I'm aiming to show virtual entity records on a subgrid on the form of a custom entity (say, Client). I have created a virtual entity, custom data provider and registered the required plugin. So far things work fine; I load the form, subgrid loads with the data from external webservice.

Now, I want to pass a string field on the form (say, Client.ExternalId) as a parameter to the retrieveMultiple plugin so that I can use this field to query the datasource.
The retriveMultiple plugin steps (registered automatically when custom data provider was set up) show that it was registered on the virtual entity and not Client entity. Since it gets executed on load of the subgrid on the Client entity form I am not sure how I can pass a field to the plugin.

Can someone please give some guidance on how to achieve this?

Version 1710 (9.2.22103.194) online

Thanks

[image]

Comment: you will have to debug your plugin and in your debug, you will find out query of type FetchExpression. This queryexpression will have relationship mentioned for example, clinet--> your virtual entity and via this you can figure out if your retrieve multiple is running from any parent entity or via view. [Take a look at this post](https://carldesouza.com/dynamics-365-retrievemultiple-plugin/) let me know if this helps.

Comment: @AnkUser As far as I know, the plugin tracer will throw an exception when you try to profile a plugin on a virtual entity.

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual entity has an N:1 relationship with the main entity and the subgrid is configured to show related records, then you can do like this:

```
// first, get the whole query
var query = context.InputParameterOrDefault<QueryExpression>("Query");
// next, get the linkEntity and then the linkFilter
var linkFilter = query.LinkEntities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LinkToEntityName == "mainEntityLogicalName").LinkCriteria;
// next, get the main entity id
var mainEntityId = linkFilter.Conditions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeName == "mainEntityIdFieldName").Values.FirstOrDefault() as Guid?;
// finally, retreive main entity to get the Client.ExternalId
var mainEntity = orgSvc.Retrieve("mainEntityLogicalName", mainEntityId.Value, new ColumnSet("Client.ExternalId"));
var clientExternalId = mainEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("Client.ExternalId");
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way will have to be if you do this client side since you want to set your sub grid when the form loads.

```
var gridContext = page.getControl("YOURGRIDNAME");
var FetchXml = `<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
                  <entity name="msep_">
                    <attribute name="mserp_entityid" />
                    <attribute name="mserp_name" />
                    <filter type="and">
                      <condition attribute="mserp_entityid" operator="eq" value="` + id + `" />
                    </filter>
                  </entity>
                </fetch>`;
gridContext.setFilterXml(FetchXml);
page.getControl("YOURGRIDNAME").refresh();
```

You can go plug-in but will have register against the ‘retrieve multiple’ message, pre-operation pipeline. The input parameter will have a fetchxml again that you can manipulate.

```
if (context.InputParameters["Query"] is FetchExpression) 
{
  var thisQuery = context.InputParameters["Query"];
  var fetchExpressionQuery = thisQuery as FetchExpression;
  fetchExpressionQuery.Query = "<fetch version'1.0'/>"
}
```